# Galaxy S4 Not Showing in ADB

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, bootloader

I want to root a Galaxy S4, yea I know it's an old phone, but perfect for what I want to do. Problem is, once I do `adb restart bootloader`, the device is no longer on the `adb devices` list, so I cannot unlock the bootloader.

Any suggestions? I am somewhat new at this so I don't know exactly what to do. Step by step would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in the bootloader mode, the device no longer communicates via `adb`, if you want to now unlock your bootloader, you have to use `fastboot`.

Also, the Samsung Galaxy S4 (except for AT&T and Verizon versions) don't have a locked bootloader, all you have to do is flash a custom recovery via Odin, then you are all good to go.

TWRP is a good option for custom recoveries these days, you can go to their website and download the `.tar` version of their recovery, then put the `.tar` file into Odin's "AP" slot and hit "Start", your device should now be loaded with a custom recovery.

Here's the link to all the information required: https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4/i9505-orig-develop/recovery-twrp-3-2-1-0-t3742880